# Programmatically adding images to OneNote 2007

Tags: xml, ms-office, onenote

I'm having trouble adding an image to a page in OneNote 2007.  I can create sections, notebooks and pages with content, but I'm having trouble adding an image to the page.

I call `UpdatePageContent` and pass in the xml but I get an invalid XML message (*hresult 0x80042001*) back.  Any assistance appreciated.  Here is the XML I'm trying to update the page with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one:Page xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2007/onenote" ID="{E1C8B8F6-6E07-4986-BD90-40E7D55DE31C}{1}{B0}" name="1" dateTime="2009-10-02T16:39:36.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2009-10-02T16:39:40.000Z">
  <one:PageSettings RTL="false" color="automatic">
    <one:PageSize>
      <one:Automatic/>
    </one:PageSize>
    <one:RuleLines visible="false"/>
  </one:PageSettings>
  <one:Title style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:17.0pt" lang="en-US">
    <one:OE author="Chapman, Jeremy" lastModifiedBy="Chapman, Jeremy" creationTime="2009-10-02T16:39:38.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2009-10-02T16:39:39.000Z" objectID="{722FED92-FCC8-45D5-89CB-A2F506E92A66}{31}{B0}" alignment="left">
      <one:T><![CDATA[1]]></one:T>
    </one:OE>
  </one:Title>
  <one:Image  format="png">
    <one:Position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
    <one:Size width="90" height="90" />
    <one:Data>aWgzVisZWZxTGNlNHQ      ...       9SSzVDWUlJPQ==</one:Data>
  </one:Image>
</one:Page>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. A year later have you found any solution?

Comment: I did get this working,  but I'd have to look through the code to see what I did, as I solved this quite some time ago...